# Обработчики в javascript

Tags: javascript

Что лучше использовать

```
    var a = document.getElementById("enter")
    a.onclick = funtion(){}
```

или

```
    a.addEnentListener("click", function(){}, false)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если ограничиваться тем примером который показан в вопросе, то a.onclick = funtion(){} проще и надежнее.

onclick - событие из DOM Level 0 и поддерживается всеми браузерами.

addEventListener - событие из DOM Level 2 и поддерживается современными браузерами, но для ИЕ младше 9 версии нужно событие навешивать через attachEvent, что может показаться менее удобным.

Преимущество addEventListener/attachEvent - возможность на одно событие повесить несколько разных обработчиков - но если в этом нет необходимости воспользуйтесь onclick.

Answer (score 0):

[Вот статья](http://learn.javascript.ru/introduction-browser-events)

Comment: [attachEvent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms536343(v=vs.85).aspx) же для IE

Comment: @AlexWindHope, извиняюсь, не знал

Comment: @Rules так я и написал для того, что-бы знали вы и те, кто будет все это читать, незачем извиняться :)